# Security risks with fakeroot?

Tags: security, compiling, root

Is there a security risk having fakeroot installed on my system?

I can't find much more than was is provided in the manpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

`fakeroot` never has "real" root privileges. It is used for example while creating a debian installer. It is then to virtually install an application *into the debian installer*, not into your "real" system.

A debian installer is actually nothing else but a scaled model of your system, with all the files, docs, manpages, possible libraries and executables inside it, exactly arranged like it will be "projected" on to your system if you run the installer.

The role as `root` of `fakeroot` is then limited to the environment of your `.deb` file, to be created. It has no privileges to act as the "real" root.